# React: Hover over components

Tags: html, css, reactjs, components

I am using CSS modules for styling my calculator app. I want the background-color of a component to change when an user hovers over it. However, I am unable to implement it. Can anyone help me?

Attaching the necessary CSS file:

```
.bstyle{
    height:14%;
    width:25%;
}

.red{
    background-color: #DC143C    ;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
}

.black{
    background-color:  #483c32 ;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in your css, but you can adapt to you needs.

```
.bstyle{
    height:14%;
    width:25%; 
}
.red{
    background-color: #DC143C    ;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
}
.black{
    background-color:  #483c32 ;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;

    &:hover span {
        opacity: 0.7;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div classsName="foo">
   
</div>
```

styles.css

```
.foo {
  background-color: red
  transition: background-color .2s linear;
}

.foo:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```